# jQuery val() indexOf not working

Tags: jquery, contains, indexof

Trying to do something if the input value contains a certain word but this doesn't work:

```
   var formMain =  $('#MainForm :input[name="Search"]');
    if ((formMain).value.indexOf('word') >= 0) {
    alert('HAS THIS WORD IN IT!');
```

Example Form:

```
<form onsubmit="return OnSubmitSearchForm(event, this);" action="/searchresults.asp" id="MainForm" name="MainForm" method="post" class="search_results_section">
            <input type="hidden" value="word" name="Search">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="Cat">
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your title mentions `val()` but you're not actually using it.  `formMain` is a jquery object and has no `value`, you should use `val()`.

```
var formMain =  $('#MainForm :input[name="Search"]');
if (formMain.val().indexOf('word') >= 0) {
    alert('HAS THIS WORD IN IT!');
}
```

Also note that `formMain` is a misleading variable name as it is not the main form but rather a jquery object which contains the search input.

Comment: I have successfully tested this.  Thank you for clarification also!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  var formMain =  $('#MainForm input[name="Search"]').val();
  if (formMain.indexOf('word') >= 0) {
    alert('HAS THIS WORD IN IT!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly you are doing mistake with selector and should use .val with selector only .... here is something for you check this http://jsfiddle.net/sahil20grover1988/V2dsn/3/