# Userscript - Check all <a>'s with a specific class and use it. (.index)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so my script will check through all `<a>`'s and find the specific  using .index and looking for a specific href string/attribute.

For example, the  I want to find, looks something like this:

```
<a class='button' href='program://personsIDhere'>
```

And there's a bunch of other  as well. So my jQuery looks like this:

```
var index = $('a').index($("a[href='program://']"))
if(index >= 0) {
    console.log(index);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, so how would I go about doing this? I want to search for the specific href value/attribute like I stated, and grab the href's value.

I tried to do something like this:
[Get Index Of Element Within UL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965825/get-index-of-element-within-ul)
[jQuery val() indexOf not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615719/jquery-val-indexof-not-working)
But I wasn't clever enough to understand it, I suppose.

Comment: What does index have to do with this ?

Comment: `var href = $("a[href='program://']").eq(2).attr('href')`

Comment: @adeneo - Did not work. Returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), and i think you must be confused with `index` and `length`, the following snippet would do the job for you.

```
var length = $("a[href^='program://']").length
if(length > 0) {
    console.log(length);
}
```

Comment: How would I go about getting the actual value? (program://personIDhere)

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop Can you please be more clear..? :) couldn't get you.

Comment: Like I stated in my question, I have something like program://personsIDhere and I want to get the whole href attribute. (I.E: program://addFriend/349134913519539)

Comment: Do you know how I would get it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the target element first then pass the element selector as the second argument in the [index-selector](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector) format of [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
var index = $("a[href='program://']").index('a')
if(index >= 0) {
    console.log(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
var length = $("a[href^='program://']").length;
if(length > 0) {
    console.log($("a[href^='program://']").attr('href'));
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

Thanks for the answers tho.